# Wildfly setup using ejb remote access and custom login module / applicationrealm is additionally called

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, jboss, wildfly

When activating a custom login module for EJB remote authentification, the applicationrealm is additionally called for authentication. Unfortunately, I do not know why.

With the current implementation the user is logged in the customlogin module and logged in the ejb. This is only successful as long as a user with same username and same password is registered in the application-users.properties. Change the user so the login does not work anymore. I am at this point not clear whether the authentication is running exclusively through application-users.properties (ApplicationRealm) or combined via application-users.properties and via custom login module. and why does it authenticate with application-users.properties.

The goal is to authenticate EJB remote access completely by custom login module.

**Following the setup:**

**EJB remote client properties:**

```
props.put("java.naming.factory.initial", "org.jboss.naming.remote.client.InitialContextFactory");  
props.put(java.naming.factory.url.pkgs, "org.jboss.ejb.client.naming");  
props.put("jboss.naming.client.ejb.context", false);  
props.put("org.jboss.ejb.client.scoped.context", true);  
props.put("endpoint.name", "client-endpoint");  
props.put("remote.connections", "default");  
props.put("remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED", false);  
props.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS", false);  
props.put("remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOPLAINTEXT", "false");  

props.put("java.naming.provider.url", "http-remoting://127.0.0.1:8080");  
props.put("remote.connection.default.host", "127.0.0.1");  
props.put("remote.connection.default.port", "8080");  
props.put("remote.connection.default.username", "username");  
props.put("remote.connection.default.password", "password");
```

**ejb url:**

```
ejb:/my-app/MyServiceImpl!com.some.MyServiceInterface
```

**standalone.xml configuration based on normal standalone.xml (not full):**

security-realm

```
<security-realm name="MyRealm">  
        <authentication>  
                    <jaas name="com.some.MyCustomLoginModule"/>  
     </authentication>  
</security-realm>
```

security-domain

```
<security-domain name="MySecurityDomain" cache-type="default">  
        <authentication>  
                <login-module code="com.some.MyCustomLoginModule" flag="required" module="login.my">  
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="user.properties"/>  
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="roles.properties"/>  
             </login-module>  
     </authentication>  
</security-domain>
```

remoting subsystem

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:3.0">  
            <endpoint/>  
            <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="MyRealm"/>  
</subsystem>
```

**Implementation:**

service impl

```
@Stateless  
@SecurityDomain("MySecurityDomain")  
@DeclareRoles("user")  
public class MyServiceImpl implements MyService {  

     private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyServiceImpl .class);  

     @Resource  
     private EJBContext ejbContext;  

     @PermitAll  
     public String getPrincipalName() {  
          logger.info("Principal: " + ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName());  
          return ejbContext.getCallerPrincipal().getName();  
     }  
}
```

service interface

```
@Remote  
public interface MyService {  
     public String getPrincipalName();  
}
```

custom login module

```
import java.security.Principal;  
import java.util.Map;  
import javax.security.auth.Subject;  
import javax.security.auth.callback.CallbackHandler;  
import javax.security.auth.login.LoginException;  
import org.jboss.logging.Logger;  
import org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsersRolesLoginModule;  

public class CustomLoginModule extends UsersRolesLoginModule {  
    private CustomPrincipal principal;  

     private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(CustomLoginModule.class);  

     @Override  
     public void initialize(Subject arg0, CallbackHandler arg1, Map<String, ?> arg2, Map<String, ?> arg3) {  
          logger.info("init module from main class");  
          super.initialize(arg0, arg1, arg2, arg3);  
     }  

     public boolean login() throws LoginException {  
          logger.info("Calling login()");  
          logger.info("User before: " + getUsername());  

          boolean login = super.login();  

          logger.info("User: " + getUsername());  
          logger.info("Password: " + getUsersPassword());  

          if (login) {  
               principal = new CustomPrincipal(getUsername(), "An user description!");  
          }  
          return login;  
     }  

     protected Principal getIdentity() {  
          return principal != null ? principal : super.getIdentity();  
     }  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found my mistake.

the realm was wrong configured

```
 <jaas name="com.some.MyCustomLoginModule"/>
```

instead of

```
 <jaas name="MySecurityDomain"/>
```

i configured the class of the login module instead of the logical name of the security domain. instead of throwing an error - the jboss does a fallback authentification. mmmhh ...

Comment: is this authentication happening when EJB invoked? is there any way to invoke the authentication before EJB call and get the subjects?

Answer (score 1):

The server-client product I work on also handles the login process completely by the back end through EJB and where the username and passwords are verified.  Wildfly is only serving our server and we don't use the Wildfly's Management console so we don't use Wildfly's `application-users`.

We simply setup the ApplicationRealm like this:

```html
<security-realm name="MyRealm">
 <authentication>
  <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*" skip-group-loading="true"/>
 </authentication>
</security-realm>
```

jboss-ejb.client.properties :

```js
remote.connections=default
remote.connection.default.host=localhost
remote.connection.default.port=8080
remote.connection.default.connect.options.org.xnio.Options.SASL_POLICY_NOANONYMOUS=false
remote.connectionprovider.create.options.org.xnio.Options.SSL_ENABLED=false
```

and the login process is handled only through our EJBs.

***NOTE**: This might not be the solution for everyone with a similar setup.  The nature of our product allows us to do this and we have a certificate in place and this all runs only internally behind our customer's networks and firewalls.*

Comment: Unfortunately, this solutionis not an option for us. but I have read the jboss doc to your solution "local default-user =$ local allowed-users=*" and found the real mis configuration. see additional answer. thank you!

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/Security+Realms